# Module to define an attribute and sort collections by that attribute

Tags: ruby

I've got a module called `Votable` that I'm using to give different classes a `votes` attribute and `vote_up` and `vote_down` methods.  However, I also want collections of `Votable` objects to be ordered by their number of votes.  Is there a way I can use this module to define this sorting behavior?

```
module Votable
  attr_reader :votes

  def votes
    @votes ||= 0
  end

  def vote_up
    @votes += 1
  end

  def vote_down
    @votes -= 1
  end
end


class Topic
  def initialize
    @comments = []
  end

  def add_comment(comment)
    @comments << comment
  end

  def comments
    # this code needs to be duplicated in every class that has a
    # collection of votables, but on a different collection
    @comments.sort { |a,b| b.votes <=> a.votes }
  end
end


class Comment
  include Votable
end
```

Comment: create a method in the module `sort_by_vote` => `sort { |a,b| b.votes <=> a.votes }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering a collection of votables is a behaviour of the collection, not of a votable.

One thing you could do is to define the spaceship operator on votables and include `Comparable`:

```
def <=>(other)
  self.votes <=> other.votes
end
```

Then sorting collections, and `sort` method, will just do the right thing.

However, I'm not too sure how smart that is - if your votables already are comparable with a different comparison operator, things might blow up in your face.